Multidimensional empirical mode decomposition in python
I am trying to perform empirical mode decomposition of two-dimensional positional data using the python code given in : MEMD python. I have two time series data for x- and y- component of position. Shall I combine the two data sets to form one single data set for giving it as input to the function ? Actually it has not been written clearly in the documentation. Could someone please help ?

According to the documentation, the memd(X) function requires X to be a multidimensional dataset, where time series are stacked as rows. In your case, this implies arranging your data as a $2 \times L$ matrix, where $L$
represents the length of each time series. Then apply the memd(X) function.

As I can see in the documentation, the X dataset has to be a 3 dimensional one. Which means that i need to construct X as np.column_stack((x_data,y_data,z_data)). With 2 dimensional data i cannot construct this matrix. So what to do ?
